# Schema validation fails with Hibernate 6 and ZonedDateTime and colum type timestamp with SQL Server and hibernate.timezone.default_storage

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have migrated an existing spring boot application to Spring 3.2.1 with Hibernate 6.4.1 (using SQL Server and PostgreSQL as persistency variants).

When starting the application, we get now following error which worked well before the update:

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [timestamp] in table [action_log]; found [timestamp (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [datetimeoffset(6) (Types#TIMESTAMP_UTC)]

The column is defined as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE action_log
(
    action_log_id           bigint       NOT NULL,
    timestamp               timestamp    NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (action_log_id)
);
```

The Java Entity as:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "action_log")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "action_log_id_generator", sequenceName = "action_log_id_seq")
public class ActionLogEntity {

    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "action_log_id_generator")
    @Column(name = "action_log_id")
    @TimeZoneStorage
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime timestamp;
    
    ...
}
```

We are aware, that with Hibernate 6 the handling for time zone values has been improved and that it's possible to either set the type individually to `@TimeZoneStorage(TimeZoneStorageType.NORMALIZE_UTC)` or by defining the behavior globally with `hibernate.timezone.default_storage=NORMALIZE_UTC`.

So we tried out the following configuration:

```
# Store everything as UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.timezone.default_storage=NORMALIZE_UTC
```

The same happens also with `datetime2`:

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [timestamp] in table [action_log]; found [datetime2 (Types#TIMESTAMP)], but expecting [datetimeoffset(6) (Types#TIMESTAMP_UTC)].

Question: How can we configure Hibernate to accept the column to be of type `timestamp` for SQL Server and drop all timezone information, as we store times anyway in UTC?

Comment: Apart from the problem i'd suggest to rename the column timestamp since it seems to be a reserved keyword since it is a column type.

Comment: Timestamp in SQL Server is not a date time, it is a row version number. As the error says, it is expecting a column of type datetimeoffset

Comment: Timestamp is a binary thing which doesn't covert to time at all, think of it like a number that keeps track of changes performed to a row. So the error was inside you all along, as the old saying goes. As to why this occurs, perhaps the old version didn't perform any checks, or something else. Why do you need this field in hibernate at all?

Comment: The same issue happens also with the field of type `datetime2`. It worked for the last 5 years this way. I am aware of the special type of `timestamp`, but as the issue is not only with `timestamp`, but also with `datetime2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a potential solution by overwriting the mapping globally. With this change at least it works with `datetime2`, but looks more like a hack to me.

```java
public class CustomSQLServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

    public CustomSQLServerDialect() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomSQLServerDialect(DialectResolutionInfo info) {
        super(info);
    }

    public CustomSQLServerDialect(DatabaseVersion version) {
        super(version);
    }

    @Override
    protected String columnType(int sqlTypeCode) {
        if (SqlTypes.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE == sqlTypeCode) {
            return "datetime2";
        }
        return super.columnType(sqlTypeCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected String castType(int sqlTypeCode) {
        if (SqlTypes.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE == sqlTypeCode) {
            return "datetime2";
        }
        return super.castType(sqlTypeCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
        JdbcTypeRegistry jdbcTypeRegistry = typeContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getJdbcTypeRegistry();
        jdbcTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE, TimestampUtcAsOffsetDateTimeJdbcType.INSTANCE);
    }

}
```